# Json get 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, silverlight

In an asp.net mvc application I have a method that returns a JsonResult to the view. It works perfectly on my local machine, however when the application is deployed on the web hosting server, when I try get this data by hitting the view's link I get a 404 Not Found in Firebug. Is there anyone who know a possible reason why this could be happening? My code snippets of how I generate the path are below:

```
    private void get_info()
    {
        var serviceUri = new Uri("/getcountrydata/" + country_name + "/" + arms[0].Name + "/" + arms[1].Name + "/" + arms[2].Name + "/" + arms[3].Name, UriKind.Relative);
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += openReadCompleted;
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
    }
```

Global.asax routing below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "getcountrydata",
           "getcountrydata/{country}/{indicator1}/{indicator2}/{indicator3}/{indicator4}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "getcountrydata" }
       );
```

The getcountrydata method is as follows:

```
public JsonResult getcountrydata(string country, string indicator1, string indicator2, string indicator3, string indicator4)
    {

       LegoData legoData = captainClimateRepostory.GetLegoData(country, indicator1, indicator2, indicator3, indicator4);

       DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LegoData));
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       ser.WriteObject(ms, legoData);

       return Json(ms.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

Comment: do you know what version of IIS your hosting provider is using?  you should be able to see it in firebug response headers.

Comment: They are using Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: use the REST client on firefox to test your service, once you get it working there you can try fixing this code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a problem with the url you are providing for the action. It is not relative in respect to the host server. Check this SO post..

[jquery ajax call to JsonResult controller method results in 404 on IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152058/jquery-ajax-call-to-jsonresult-controller-method-results-in-404-on-iis6)

Comment: The problem is I cannot use the Url.Action() helper method where I generate the query because that is in a silverlight project and you cannot reference System.Web.Mvc in there?

Comment: Why can't you reference System.Web.MVC there?

Comment: You cant add the System.Web.MVC dll to the silverlight project. It only allows you to add Silverlight specific dlls.

Comment: And you can't use  the Url.Action() helper method in a JavaScript file either. See how I do it correctly in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inside Silverlight you can build a URL relative to the page hosting your XAP:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "../getcountrydata/");
```

Even better - relative to your XAP:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri, "../getcountrydata/");
```

Some more info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/03/13/get-silverlight-xap-and-hosting-page-url.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tanveer-Ibn- Haresh is correct -you are providing a URL assumes app is running at the root. My tutorial  [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery][1] 
  [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc shows how to do this correctly.

1. Fiddler will show you the problem instantly.
2. You should test locally with IIS before deployment.