# JQUERY Ajax call returns IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found in ASP.net MVC5 using VS 2017 Community

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've been scratching my head all this time. My code is working on IIS Express in VS Studio 2017 but after deploying into IIS Server 10 it says: `Failed to load resource: POST http://localhost:99 jquery?v=2u0aRenDpYxArEyILB59ETSCA2cfQkSMlxb6jbMBqf81:1 /Home/ListDevices 404 (Not Found) IIS 10.0.`. The server can't find the ajax url. I'm using ADO.net for other database table manipulation. I've tried this solution [asp.net mvc5 ajax post returns 404 after switching to IIS 7.5 from IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152058/jquery-ajax-call-to-jsonresult-controller-method-results-in-404-on-iis6?rq=1) and also this [asp.net mvc ajax post returns 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371688/asp-net-mvc-ajax-post-returns-404-not-found). All of them is not working to solve my problem. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Here is my code so far.

**HTML Added script**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Device-View.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead style="color:black">

                            </thead>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
```

**Jquery Side (Device-View.js)**

```
var datum;  
$(document).ready(function () {   
   $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",

    buttons: [
        {
            "extend": 'print', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>&nbsp&nbsp Print', "className": 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
            exportOptions: {
                //columns: ':visible'
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            }
        },

        {
            "extend": 'excel', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>&nbsp&nbsp Excel', "className": 'btn btn-success btn-sm exportExcel',
            exportOptions: {
                //columns: ':visible'
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            }
        },
        { "extend": 'colvis', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>&nbsp Hide Column', "className": 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', "columnDefs": [{ "targets": -1, "visible": false }] },
    ],

    order: [[0, "desc"]],

    "columnDefs": [{
        "defaultContent": "",
        "targets": "_all"
    }],

    ajax: {
        url: "/Home/ListDevices",
        //url: '@Url.Action("ListDevices", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            var data = jQuery.map(result, function (key, item) {
                return [[key.DeviceCode, key.PrevDeviceCode, key.SerialNum, key.NameDescription, key.ClassDescription, key.ModelDescription, key.LocationDescription, key.StatusDescription ]];
            });

            datum = data;

            $('#myDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData(datum);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
            //alert("Error");
        }
    },


    columns: [
        { title: "Code" },
        { title: "Prev. Code" },
        { title: "Serial No." },
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Class" },
        { title: "Model" },
        { title: "Location" },
        { title: "Status" },
    ]

});

});
```

**Route Config**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Walkin",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ); 
    }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnet-sample;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**HomeController**

```
public JsonResult ListDevices()
    {
        return Json(empDB.ListAllDevices(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Model**

```
//Return list of all Status Setting data
    public List<Devices> ListAllDevices()
    {
        List<Devices> lst = new List<Devices>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AllDevices", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lst.Add(new Devices
                {
                    IDevice = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["IDDevice"]),
                    StatusDescription = rdr["Status_Desc"].ToString(),
                });
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Not related, but both your routes are the same and only the first one will ever be executed (both allow for between 0 and 3 segments)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have Admin view and user's view(walkin) so I created 2 routes in order to remove buttons(add, edit, delete) in the user's view.

Comment: I assume you did not understand my comment? The 2nd (Default) route is pointless. Remove one of the other (but its not the cause of your error). What are the full details of the error?

Comment: @JAMES BRYAN B. Juventud: Your ajax call is POST method so did you mentioned [HttpPost] on above JsonResult ListDevices() action method?

Comment: And the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is not required since its a POST

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah your right dude the second route is pointless. ;)

Comment: @NamanUpadhyay The function doesn't have [HttPost] above. Should I add [HttpPost]?

Comment: Yes, because if you dont add that it will consider as GET method but your method is POST so you need to add that

Comment: @NamanUpadhyay I tried to add but still the error is `404 Not found`.

Comment: @JAMES BRYAN B. Juventud: Also did you removed {JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet} ?

Comment: @NamanUpadhyay Yes. I already removed `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. So my return now is `return Json(empDB.ListAllDevices());` still the error persists.

Comment: @JAMES BRYAN B. Juventud: Have you tried with this url: '@Url.Action("ListDevices", "Home")' which you already commented?

Comment: Based on the edited error message, I can only assume that you script is in a separate js file and that you are using `@Url.Action(...)` - that is razor code and not parsed in external files. You need to generate the url in the main view and pass it to the js function (e.g. as a `data` attribute of the element you are handling

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah. I haven't changed the returned error. I just testing it using `@url.action..`. See my edit and also I already added whole .js script. Hope it can help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is needed because it will generate a reply: `This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to the third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET request, set JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.`

Comment: @NamanUpadhyay Putting `[HttpPost]` above the function will generate response `The resource can't be found.`

Comment: But you specified `type: "POST",` in the ajax options  (so you have not shown the real code if you are getting that error)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Upon loading jquery `document.ready` the datatable works fine, but when I try to; say add data/edit/delete it will pop up that message. Seems weird, I used jquery in loading page also after add/edit/delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved my problem. The problem is in calling separated Javascript file. Maybe I've missed some configurations before calling the separated JS file and works like a charm. I've appended the JS content within the view. Please change the url ajax to this `url: '@Url.Action("function", "Controller")',` Hope this can help to others.

```
`Your HTML code here....`

@section Scripts{
<!-- JS -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var datum;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDataTable').DataTable({

            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",

            buttons: [
                {
                    "extend": 'print', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>&nbsp&nbsp Print', "className": 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
                    }
                },

                {
                    "extend": 'excel', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>&nbsp&nbsp Excel', "className": 'btn btn-success btn-sm exportExcel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
                    }
                },
                { "extend": 'colvis', "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>&nbsp Hide Column', "className": 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', "columnDefs": [{ "targets": -1, "visible": false }] },
            ],

            order: [[0, "desc"]],

            "columnDefs": [{
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": "_all"
            }],

            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("ListDevices", "Home")',

                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    var data = jQuery.map(result, function (key, item) {
                        return [[key.DeviceCode, key.PrevDeviceCode, key.SerialNum, key.NameDescription, key.ClassDescription, key.ModelDescription, key.LocationDescription, key.StatusDescription ]];
                    });

                    datum = data;

                    $('#myDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData(datum);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            },

            columns: [
                { title: "Code" },
                { title: "Prev. Code" },
                { title: "Serial No." },
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Class" },
                { title: "Model" },
                { title: "Location" },
                { title: "Status" },
            ]

        });

    });

</script>
}
```