# Jquery ajax url when publishing asp.net mvc project on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, url

When I use jQuery post function in my js file, like this:

```
$.post("/map/GetWindowedMapInfo", { 
    width: windowWidth * 2, 
    height: windowHeight * 2, 
    xCoord: winXCoord, 
    yCoord: winYCoord }, function (data) {...});
```

It work well in vs2010 developer server, but failed when publishing the ASP.NET MVC project on IIS, the associated controller function did not run anymore, because url was wrong.
I have to use `'<%= Url.Content("~/map/GetWindowedMapInfo") %>'` to replace old url, but this can only work in the .aspx or .ascx file. Do you know any method to make a usable url in js file, not using `<%=Url.Content(...) %>` function, because I don't want to put my js file in aspx page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/376644/497356

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be hardcoding urls like this:

```
$.post("/map/GetWindowedMapInfo", { 
    ...    
});
```

Instead you should use URL helpers:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("GetWindowedMapInfo", "map")", { 
    ...    
});
```